# Why wasn't the phosphine in Venus' atmosphere detected by space probes?

Tags: atmosphere, venus, spectroscopy

Today, it was announced that [phosphine has been found in Venus' atmosphere](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/2020/09/possible-sign-of-life-found-on-venus-phosphine-gas/), rekindling the discussion about the possibility of extraterrestrial life. Venus has been visited by space probes for [about 50 years now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus#Exploration); how come none of these detected the presence of this gas? Much data was gathered about the composition of Venus' atmosphere, but not the presence of this molecule. Were we simply not looking for it, or were the instruments back then not precise enough to detect the amount of phosphine?

Comment: I think you might be overestimating the number of Venusian missions & underestimating the density of the atmosphere...

Comment: And who would think to look for phosphine there anyway? Although a case may be made for it (phosphorus compounds are known in the Venusian atmosphere and so is the similarly reduced hydrogen sulfide), it would not really he intuituve.

Answer (score 13):

From the recently published paper [*Phosphine gas in the cloud decks of Venus*](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-020-1174-4).

> The presence of PH<sub>3</sub> implies an atmospheric, surface or subsurface source of phosphorus, or delivery from interplanetary space. The only measured values of atmospheric phosphorus on Venus come from Vega descent probes, which were only sensitive to phosphorus as an element, so its chemical speciation is not known. No phosphorus species have been reported at the planetary surface.

Comment: Your linked paper says "PH3 is found elsewhere in the Solar System only in the reducing atmospheres of giant planets ([12](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/002228529290026K), 13)" and the first reference discusses FTIR around a wavelength of 4–5 μm. You don't need to drop a probe to sample the atmosphere to detect phosphine as an element, just do spectroscopy. So the question is really why spectroscopic results were possible for Jupiter and Saturn but not for Venus, until now.

Comment: @uhoh there could be the issue with interference.  I have read they still have to verify phosphine is not really SO2.  Would not be a problem on the giant planets!

Comment: @OscarLanzi I heard from the YouTube channel Cool Worlds that they detected PH3 with a sigma of 15, which would indicate a very strong likelihood it was detected correctly.

Comment: @OscarLanzi the paper linked above goes into quite a bit of  detail on how they could rule out SO2 (around Fig. 4)

Comment: @uhoh  The published paper in the answer  in the Results chapter says the PH3 rotational transition at 1,123 *mm* wavelength was sought, that 's for instance *outside* all the bands that Venus Express used for more than 8 years.  If all the other space probes also had no spectrometers in the *mm* range than that could be an explanation for not detecting the PH3.

Comment: @Cornelisinspace oh that's interesting! Those are millimeter waves, basically radio astronomy. [The JCMT](https://www.eaobservatory.org/jcmt/) is a 15 meter radio dish, and 1.123 mm corresponds to about 267 GHz. See [Spectroscopic parameters of phosphine, PH3, in its ground vibrational state](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1138) for some review of studies of several planets for PH3 using several different techniques. [Band 6 of ALMA](https://www.eso.org/public/teles-instr/alma/receiver-bands/) covers 1.1 to 1.4 mm so there might even be higher resolution images of Venus, but I don't know.

Comment: @Cornelisinspace I just saw this: http://www.ericweisstein.com/research/thesis/ It's an online version of [Eric Weisstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_W._Weisstein)'s thesis!!! Here are the chapters related to Jupiter and Saturn specific to PH3: http://www.ericweisstein.com/research/thesis/node66.html

Comment: From what I understand the precise radio spectrum of PH3 is not trivial to get. https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/when-we-finally-find-aliens-they-might-smell-terrible/ says "Getting spectra for phosphine alone took me four years". (It may refer to "ExoMol line lists – VII. The rotation–vibration spectrum of phosphine up to 1500 K", 2015.)

Comment: @uhoh Good to have relevant links for this subject ! From the Introduction chapter : "It is therefore fortunate rhat the PH3 molecule has *two strong observable* rotational transitions in the millimeter-submillimeter portion of the spectrum (J=1-0 at 267 Ghz  and J=3-2 at 800 Ghz)." And band 10 of ALMA includes that 800 Ghz.  And from the article in the answer: " However, conformation is always important for a single-transition detection. Other PH3 transitions should be sought,.. "