# Could the phosphorus in phosphine in the Venus atmosphere probably produced by cosmic ray spallation of sulfur?

Tags: atmosphere, planetary-science, venus, cosmic-radiation

Reading the following questions and their answers:

- [Why wasn't the phosphine in Venus' atmosphere detected by space probes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46526/12102)
- [Phosphine, yes -- but where are the organic compounds on Venus?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46539/12102)

the second provides a link that, "phosphine is no more." However, my imagination was thinking elsewhere -- the Earth.
[Chlorine-m34 arises from cosmic ray spallation on Argon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmogenic_nuclide#Cosmogenic_nuclides).

By analogy, could phosphorus arise from cosmic ray spallation on sulfur in sulfur dioxide, sulfuric acid or hydrogen sulfide?

(Space Exploration aspect) Or fantasy again, in future human floating settlement, shall human explore this following option to supply phosphorus to the settlement or station? Packages of Venusian atmospheric sulfur species are exposed in the path where most incoming cosmic rays shine to make more phosphorus. The phosphorus are then mined.

Comment: [Neutron produced Phosphorus-32 in the Barwell and St. Severin Meteorites](https://www.nature.com/articles/213052a0)

Comment: Welcome.  How is this question connected to space exploration?  If humans had never ventured beyond the atmosphere, this question would (in the proper forum) still be an answerable question.  Therefore, space exploration has nothing to do with this question, and it is off-topic here.

Comment: @DrSheldon we have [253 questions tagged with planetary-science](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-science) and these being on-topic here has been [discussed at length in meta](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=planetary+science). After reviewing all of that are you still convinced that the effect of cosmic rays and energetic particles in the space environment near Venus on it's atmosphere, something that *has been and will be further explored in space* is off-topic here *and that answers must quickly be prevented*

Comment: @uhoh: Yes, but it still needs to have some connection to space exploration.  This question does not; it is theoretical and has no bearing on space missions.  We have questions on food, but that does not make every question about food on-topic.  I have no problem with the question being migrated where it can be properly answered.

Comment: @DrSheldon so we can be certain that all answers here will be *improper answers*? We can know that they will not contain any observations or experimental results that overlap with the exploration of space? We know this with *such a level of confidence*  that we must prevent them before they are written?

Comment: @DrSheldon cosmic ray spallation [produces the electrons trapped in Earth's inner Van Allen radiation belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Allen_radiation_belt#Inner_belt). and [Nuclear spallation occurs naturally in Earth's atmosphere owing to the impacts of cosmic rays, and also on the surfaces of bodies in space such as meteorites and the Moon. Evidence of cosmic ray spallation (also known as "spoliation") is seen on outer surfaces of bodies, and gives a means of measuring the length of time of exposure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spallation#Nuclear_spallation)

Comment: @DrSheldon [my discussion of planetary science](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51762/?noredirect=1#comment170538_51762) demonstrates that questions here absolutely do not have to be "[about space missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51762/is-the-phosphorus-in-phosphine-in-the-venus-atmosphere-produced-by-cosmic-ray-sp?noredirect=1#comment170539_51762)" to be on-topic here. Once something has been decided we should stick to it, or move to change it. The "about space missions" thing is a false flag.

Comment: **voting to re-open** as this question is 100% on-topic and should never have been insta-closed and answer authors should not have been blocked from answering. [You might not get the best answer here, but planetary science is considered on topic, and has been from nearly the beginning of the site.](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1307/12102) We do not close questions as "better asked on..." or "better answered on...".